# How to export database with diagrams in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, export, diagram

I have tried to export a SQL Server database to a `.bacpac` file, but when I import the file, the database diagrams were not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The diagrams are stored as data in a table (sysdiagrams), so I guess you'll need a .dacpac